# LARAVEL: I want to know if a user entered data in the database today and show on the blade a yes or a no

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to know if a user entered data in the database today and show on the blade a yes or a no

The user ID has a relation with the table called Review_table that I want to consult

Comment: Can you give a little but more information? i.e.  is there a specific table or just any table? If it's specific table, is there a relationship between that table and the user? If not, is your app set up to record when a user has entered data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `review_table` has `updated_at` or at least `created_at` field

You need something like

```
$today = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
$entered_data_today = $user->reviews()->whereDate('updated_at',$today)->isNotEmpty();
```